# Coming from C#, How do I code simple multi-threading in Java?

Tags: java, c#, multithreading

I am new to Java and do not have a lot of experience with multi-threading. Here is some multi-threading code I have in C#.net:

```
public class MultiThread 
{
    Thread t1,t2,t3;

    public MultiThread()
    {
        t1=new Thread(m1);

        t2=new Thread(m2);

        t1.start();

        t2.start();
    }

    public void m1()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)

        Console.Write Line(i);
    }

    public void m2()
    {
        for (int i=0;i<100;i++)

        Console.Write Line(i);
    }

    public static void main() 
    {
        MultiThread mm=new MultiThread();
    }
}
```

As per the multi Threading definition(executing sub processes concurrently) m1() and m2() are two different sub processes ...so in this program they(m1 and m2) execute simultaneously

If we look at this Java mult-threading code:

```
public class MultiThread extends Thread {

    public void run(){
        for (int i=0;i<100;i++){

            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MultiThread t1=new MultiThread();

        MultiThread t2=new MultiThread();

        t1.start();

        t2.start();
    }
}
```

This code contains only one method (a sub process or only one thread).

How can I achieve multi-threading in Java?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Look up the javadoc for classes Thread and Runnable

Comment: Just because there's only one method doesn't mean there's only one thread. You could create two threads in C# using one method, too. (And given that `m1` and `m2` do the same thing, they *should* be just a single method...)

Comment: so Can you please give me example in java ....how java do multithreading using two methods....they should run simultaneously...m1 and m2 do same thing ...just i took as example...any they run simultaneously....

Comment: You also won't be able to execute this Java code, because the MultiThread class you have does not have a `start()` method. Instead of calling `t1.start()` you should call `t1.run()`

Comment: @McAdam331 It extends `Thread`, so inherits the `start()` method.

Comment: Whoops, nice catch. Sorry!

Comment: my class extends thread...so it acquires the properties of parent thread.....so it will run perfectly....

Comment: Note, in the usual computer terminology, threads are not subprocesses. Threads share address space within a single process. Subprocess is a process launched by another process, and is a separate process with its own memory etc. So your multithreading definition is wrong.

Comment: Do not extend `Thread`, implement `Runnable` (or with Java 8 you can use a method handle or lambda) and feed that to a normal `Thread`-constructor.

Comment: Also, what do you mean `t1.run()` and `t2.run()` don't run simultaneously? Are you sure?

Comment: t1.run() and t2.run() both run simutaneously....but they falls on same method....but see we go for multithreding to limit the limitations of single thread....in singlethread, each method execute one after other...so,in multithreding i want to see how 2 methods execute simultaneously...so i need program like c#.net to understand in better way...

Comment: @user3744311 I don't think you understand threading correctly: if you execute the same method from two different threads it will run concurrently unless some form of synchronization is used.

Comment: In the C# example, the m1() method and the m2() method are _identical_.  The program would produce the same (unpredictable) output if you created both threads using m1() and just got rid of m2().  Then, the Java example would not look so different.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the exact same in Java 8 using method handles:

```
public class MultiThread {

    Thread t1,t2;

    public MultiThread() {
        t1=new Thread(this::m1);
        t2=new Thread(this::m2);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

    public void m1() {
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
            System.out.println(i);
    }

    public void m2() {
        for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
            System.out.println(i);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MultiThread mm=new MultiThread();
    }
}
```

Note however because of the synchronization in `System.out.println` it will probably execute serially anyway (or only start to interleave for significantly higher numbers than 100 iterations.